# How to resolve IndexError: list assignment index out of range using array inside loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm new to python. I'm creating 2 arrays `file_name`(stores name of the files) and `path`(stores paths of files). Values of `path` array are assigned inside while loop. But I'm getting the error:

**IndexError: list assignment index out of range in Python**

I had already wasted several hours on this one, but haven't got the output as I expected. So, can you please let me know where I have made the mess? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**My Code:**

```
file_name = ['abc','xyz','pqr','mno','def','ghi','rst','uvw','jkl']
path = []

count = 0
while count < 9:
    path[count] = "D:\\Work\\"+file_name[count]+".csv"
    print (path[count])
    count = count + 1
```

**Expected Output:**

```
D:\\Work\\abc.csv
D:\\Work\\xyz.csv
D:\\Work\\pqr.csv
D:\\Work\\mno.csv
D:\\Work\\def.csv
D:\\Work\\ghi.csv
D:\\Work\\rst.csv
D:\\Work\\uvw.csv
D:\\Work\\jkl.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the append method.

```
file_name = ['abc','xyz','pqr','mno','def','ghi','rst','uvw','jkl']
path = []

count = 0
while count < 9:
    path.append("D:\\Work\\"+file_name[count]+".csv")
    print (path[count])
    count = count + 1
```

You will get your expected output.

Answer (score 4):

You can't access `path[count]` and assign something to it if `path[count]` doesn't already exist.

To create a new list, use `.append()`. You don't need to keep track of a counter at all (it's rarely necessary to do a C-style loop in Python; the pythonic way is to iterate over the elements of a list/tuple/dictionary directly):

```
file_name = ['abc','xyz','pqr','mno','def','ghi','rst','uvw','jkl']
path = []

for item in file_name:
    newpath = "D:\\Work\\" + item + ".csv"
    # or better: newpath = r"D:\Work\{}.csv".format(item)
    path.append(newpath)
    print(newpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to append an item to the list. It would look like that then:

```
file_name = ['abc','xyz','pqr','mno','def','ghi','rst','uvw','jkl']
path = []

count = 0
while count < 9:
    path.append("D:\\Work\\"+file_name[count]+".csv")
    print (path[count])
    count = count + 1
```

Since when you created an empty list, it had no items, thus accessing it via index didn't work. You can also skip the `while` loop and use some `Python` sugar to get the same effect:

```
file_name = ['abc','xyz','pqr','mno','def','ghi','rst','uvw','jkl']
path = ['D:\\Work\\' + x + '.csv' for x in file_name]
for p in path:
    print(p)
```