# How to sort a dictionary in python using enumerate?

Tags: python, dictionary, enumerate, sorteddictionary

I have the following code

```
for index,(key,value) in enumerate(dict_var.items()):
    sorted_dict[index] = (key, value)

print("The sorted list is:{}".format(sorted_dict))
```

where

- **dict_var** is a dictionary.
- **sorted_dict** is a list that stores the keys and values of dict_var in a sorted order.

can anybody explain why this code doesn't work?

I get this error:

> sorted_dict[index] = (key, value)
>   IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve IndexError: list assignment index out of range using array inside loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409940/how-to-resolve-indexerror-list-assignment-index-out-of-range-using-array-inside)

Comment: Why do you want to use enumerate? It will simply produce the ordering already present in the dictionary, not sort anything. You can produce a list of the sorted items using ``sorted(dict_var.items())``.

Comment: You can also treat sorted_dict as a dict, not a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted_dict = [] 
sorted_dict[0] = 1 #IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The index is specifically used to access an existing position in a python list, and does not silently create the list to accomodate out of range indexes. The issue has nothing to do with enumerate.

you can simply use a list's .append() to add items at the end. 
Example:

```
sorted_dict = []
for key,value in dict_var.items():
    sorted_dict.append((key, value))

print("The sorted list is:{}".format(sorted_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the index error because the len of the `dict_var` is larger than the len of the `sorted_dict`.  To avoid this error, make certain that the size of the list is larger or the same size as the len of the `sorted_dict`. If you could show us what the `sorted_dict` looks like before you run the code that would also help.  Also, it might not be a good idea to name a list `sorted_dict`.  `sorted_list` would be better.  You can also avoid this error with:

```
for key, value in dict_var.items():
    sorted_dict.append((key, value))
```